# Flutter iOS error: Unable to read file at path /Users/dekstop/ios/firebase_app_id_file.json

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

After adding Firebase GoogleService-Info.plist getting this error when run on iOS Emulator with Mac book m1 pro

> error: Unable to read file at path
> /Users/dekstop/iOS/firebase_app_id_file.json

> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

pubspec.yaml

```
  get: ^4.6.1
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  get_storage: ^2.0.3

  badges: ^2.0.2
  country_code_picker:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/parmarravi/CountryCodePicker.git

  retrofit: ^3.0.1+1
  path_provider: ^2.0.9
  dio: ^4.0.4
  json_annotation: ^4.4.0

  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  google_fonts: ^2.3.1
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3

  flutter_screenutil: ^5.3.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  pinput: ^2.2.6
  flutter_neumorphic: ^3.2.0
  fl_chart: ^0.50.1

  image_cropper: ^1.5.1
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.1.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+11


  url_launcher: ^6.0.20
  device_info_plus: ^3.2.2
  share_plus: ^4.0.3
  connectivity_plus: ^2.2.1
  package_info_plus: ^1.4.0

  firebase_core: ^1.14.0
  firebase_analytics: ^9.1.3
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.6.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.12
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.11
  firebase_database: ^9.0.9
  firebase_storage: ^10.2.10
  firebase_messaging: ^11.2.12
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^4.1.2
  firebase_app_check: ^0.0.4


  lottie: ^1.2.2
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  animate_do: ^2.1.0
  animations: ^2.0.2
  flutter_staggered_animations: ^1.0.0
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  animated_text_kit: ^4.2.1
  liquid_swipe: ^2.1.1
  flutter_countdown_timer: ^4.1.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  adaptive_dialog: ^1.5.0

  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.4.0
  sms_autofill: ^2.2.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.4
  webview_flutter: ^3.0.1
  youtube_player_flutter: ^8.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  json_serializable: ^6.1.5
  build_runner: ^2.1.8
  retrofit_generator: ^4.0.1

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
```

Already Tried to clean project and do pod install it does not work

Comment: can you share your json file location in project and also check your bundle id in your json file which download from firebase console.

Comment: This issue has been logged here and has a temporary fix in it. https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8376

Answer (score 2):

This is how I am able to solve this issue for temporary

Open Code in Xcode.

Got to Runner > Build Phase > Firebase Crashlytics and remove or uncomment the line

[image]